# Apify - How to Enqueue URL Variations Efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, apify

I am creating a new actor in Apify with Cheerio to read an input file of URLs and return primarily two items: (1) the HTTP status code and (2) the HTML title.  As part of our process, I would like to be able to try up to 4 variations of each input URL, such as:

1. HTTP://WWW.SOMEURL.COM
2. HTTPS://WWW.SOMEURL.COM
3. HTTP://SOMEURL.COM
4. HTTPS://SOMEURL.COM

If one of the 4 variations is successful, then the process should ignore the other variations and move to the next input URL.

I read the original input list into a RequestList, and then would like to create the variations in a RequestQueue.  Is this the most efficient way to do it?  Please see code below, and thank you!

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const {
    utils: { enqueueLinks },
} = Apify;
const urlParse = require('url');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const input = await Apify.getInput();
    const inputFile = input.inputFile;
    console.log('INPUT FILE: ' + inputFile);
    
    const requestList = await Apify.openRequestList('urls', [
        { requestsFromUrl: inputFile, userData: { isFromUrl: true } },
    ]);
    const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();

    const proxyConfiguration = await Apify.createProxyConfiguration();

    const handlePageFunction = async ({ $, request, response }) => {
        let parsedHost = urlParse.parse(request.url).host;
        let simplifiedHost = parsedHost.replace('www.', '');
        
        const urlPrefixes = ['HTTP://WWW.', 'HTTPS://WWW.', 'HTTP://', 'HTTPS://'];
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < urlPrefixes.length; i++) {
            let newUrl = urlPrefixes[i] + simplifiedHost;
            console.log('NEW URL: ' + newUrl);
            await requestQueue.addRequest({ url: newUrl });
        }
  
        console.log(`Processing ${request.url}`);
        const results = {
            inputUrl: request.url,
            httpCode: response.statusCode,
            title: $('title').first().text().trim(),
            responseUrl: response.url
        };
        await Apify.pushData(results);
    };

    const crawler = new Apify.CheerioCrawler({
        proxyConfiguration,
        maxRequestRetries: 0,
        handlePageTimeoutSecs: 60,
        requestTimeoutSecs: 60,
        requestList,
        requestQueue,
        handlePageFunction,   
        handleFailedRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
            await Apify.pushData({ inputUrl: request.url, httpCode: '000', title: '', responseUrl: ''});
        }
    });

    await crawler.run();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create your URL list beforehand. the `handlePageFunction` is only used for the actual scraping part, and you should only have the `Apify.pushData` there:

```js
    //...

    const initRequestList = await Apify.openRequestList('urls', [
        { requestsFromUrl: inputFile },
    ]);
    
    const parsedRequests = [];
    let req;

    while (req = await initRequestList.fetchNextRequest()) {
      const parsedHost = urlParse.parse(req .url).host;
      const simplifiedHost = parsedHost.replace('www.', '');
        
      const urlPrefixes = ['HTTP://WWW.', 'HTTPS://WWW.', 'HTTP://', 'HTTPS://'];

      for (let i = 0; i < urlPrefixes.length; i++) {
        let newUrl = urlPrefixes[i] + simplifiedHost;
        console.log('NEW URL: ' + newUrl);
        parsedRequests.push({ 
          url: newUrl,
          userData: { isFromUrl: true }
        });
      }
    } 

    const requestList = await Apify.openRequestList('starturls', parsedRequests);

    //...

    const crawler = new Apify.CheerioCrawler({
        proxyConfiguration,
        maxRequestRetries: 0,
        handlePageTimeoutSecs: 60,
        requestTimeoutSecs: 60,
        handlePageFunction,   
        requestList,
        handleFailedRequestFunction: async ({ request }) => {
            await Apify.pushData({ inputUrl: request.url, httpCode: '000', title: '', responseUrl: ''});
        }
    });

    //...
```

`requestsFromUrl` is a greedy function that tries to parse all URLs from to the given resource. so you'll have to perform the processing as an additional step.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code.  I have ended up going a different route, but the pattern was extremely useful for creating a separate function to parse the URLs.